# React Router Link Persists after Page Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have managed to get my react-router to navigate to another page on my website however after it's done redirecting the link or button in this case still persists on the other page (login.js).

Can someone explain to me why this happens, and how I get it to not render on my page?

App.js

```
import Login from "./login";
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Routes, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleClick = () => {
        navigate("/login");
    }

 return (
  <div className="Main">
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
    
    <button onClick={handleClick} type="button" />
</div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Login.js

```
[![import React from "react";

export default function Login() {

    return (
        <div className="Login">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>
     )}
```

Comment: This is happening because you have put your button as global or outside of route it means if you visit any route it will appear

Comment: The login button is unconditionally rendered. Where do you want the login button to be rendered? Only in the `Login` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you clearly look your routes are working inside a div which means anything along with routes will be shown on the page permanently even if your route changes.**